# 76 Toyota Hiace radiator drain

Tags: radiator

I have been trying to locate the drain for the radiator in my Toyota Hiace, but I can't seem to find it. Can anyoe give me a detailed description of where it is?

Comment: More than likely you'd just have to pull the bottom radiator hose and make a mess (unfortunately).

Answer (score 3):

Check the left side (as you sit in the vehicle) of the radiator. It will be at the bottom and possibly hidden by the plastic fan shroud. It may look like a wing nut shaped plug or a conventional petcock. Or the right hand side about 1 inch from the bottom, on the front of the radiator, just looks like a bolt.